# Find my iPhone: Can everyone who i've shared my location with see each other's location?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone, find-my-friends, find-my

I want to add someone on Find my iPhone, but I don't want the people I already have my location shared with to see his location.

I've previously only had this with my family so we all have each other added.

Will the extra person be kept separate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can everyone who i've shared my location with see each other's location?

No. Find my Friends would not automatically show everyones location to everyone.

> Will the extra person be kept separate?

Yes.